# Launching mpv from a .desktop entry with the clipboard as argument

Tags: launcher, .desktop, clipboard, xclip, mpv-media-player

I'm trying to make a submenu entry on a .desktop application file that launches a youtube address with mpv. The youtube url is copied from the clipboard.
Inside gnome-terminal this works fine:

```
xclip -o | xargs mpv
```

But if I make a .desktop action like this:

```
[Desktop Action mpv]
Name=mpv clipboard
Comment=Play the url on the clipboard with mpv
Exec=xclip -o | xargs mpv
```

It doesn't work. I have tried putting gnome-terminal -x before it, but it still doesn't work. How can it be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A pipeline is a shell feature, and .desktop launching does not involve a shell. You can use something like:

```
Exec=sh -c 'xclip -o | xargs mpv'
```

Or (depending on what's in the clipboard):

```
Exec=sh -c 'mpv "$(xclip -o)"'
```

Or put the command in an executable script file somewhere and use `Exec=/path/to/script`.

Comment: Great! I assigned a keyboard shortcut to `mpv "$xclip -o"` in Kubuntu 18.04. No need for a .desktop file.